# Meaning of Quite?"Quite how that misunderstanding arose, maybe it was lost in translation, I don't know, but clearly they have all been looked after

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, conjunctions

This is from the BBC [Disturbance in London Immigration Center](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-63525332)

**"Quite how that misunderstanding arose, maybe it was lost in translation, I don't know, but clearly they have now all been looked after,"** he said.

What is the function of **"quite"** in the sentence? I checked the dictionary and couldn't see a meaning that sit well.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it means 'exactly' (or one of its synonyms).

*"Exactly how that misunderstanding arose, maybe it was lost in translation, I don't know, but clearly they have now all been looked after," he said."*

Might be make it clearer.